# CSS/HTML alignment of items in an item grid not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, magento

i have a problem with the CSS of a section of my site. The products as it is being shown in the product grid, does not come in order if the screen is too small.

For example, if you go to this site: http://pcsg.asia/shop-by-category/exfoliants.html?limit=9
and view this site on a screen larger than 30", you will have no problem seeing that the items are all in order and next to each other. **Use the grid mode.**

However, if you access this site on a screen any smaller than 24" or so, you will see that the products are not displaying in the correct multiples(i.e. 2 in one row, 1 in one row, then 2 again)

**How do i align it such that the display of all the products will fit nicely to each other, and not have irregular rows? Thanks!**

I am using Magento Go, and you can check out the CSS using your browser's development tool.

Thanks!

Comment: How many products do you want to show in a row?

Comment: i want to show 3 in a row. Ideally, it will be based on a browser's width, too.

Comment: try the css fix i posted below. Will update how to make 3 in a row and alignment related to that soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will align the items properly 4 in a row, but will mess up the image when the screen size increases and reduces

```
.products-grid li.item{
    width: 225px; // remove this line and add below style
    width:24%;
}
.products-grid .product-image{
    width: 225px; // remove this line and add below style
    width:100%;
}
```

***Or you can use this***

To change the column count from 4 to 3 in the category page, add the below code to your app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Now to align the list items 3 in a row for all the screens properly use the below css

```
.products-grid li.item{
    width: 225px;
    float:left; //Remove this line
    display:inline; //Remove this line
    display:inline-block; //add this line
    margin-right:1px; // remove this line
}
```

This will set 3 items in a row for all the screens and since the `display` is set to `inline-block`, `margin` will be added automatically to each item to position it appropriately in a row.

Try this out

Comment: Okay some progress, making width:24% for .products-grid li.item will result in items being in properly ordered rows, though the image is slightly off from the text.

when u say add below style, do you mean element.style.. or? 

Thanks for help so far

Comment: yes. I am updating my answer to how to set the column count to 3 and then you can use your old styles withe fixed widths.

Comment: checking now! hold on

Comment: added everything you said, though i think the issue is that the XML is not being updated correctly. I'm using magento go, so i placed that XML chunk into the Custom Design tab for one of the categories and it still shows 4 columns instead of 3.

Comment: @user2829836 I am assuming that you are using custom package and the category page uses magento default `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` file. In that case the above code should work. To check you can add the `setCoulumnCount` in the `catalog.xml` as said in the answer in this link. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/.../viewthread/210972/<br/>But modifying the magento files are not recommended.

Comment: i actually use Magento Go, which is one below enterprise. So i cant change list.phtml, or local.xml.

Comment: i will however accept the width:24%; fix haha. thanks.

Comment: When you try to update in Custom design tab just use this `<reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>
    </reference>` no need `<catalog_category_default>`